# Django count RawQuerySet

Tags: python, django, count

Hay, I'm using django 1.2 and i want to know how to count rows from a raw queryset(RawQuerySet).

The traditional .count() method doesn't work.

Heres my query

```
query = "SELECT *, ((ACOS(SIN(%s * PI() / 180) * SIN(lat * PI() / 180) + COS(%s * PI() / 180) * COS(lat * PI() / 180) * COS((%s - lon) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS distance FROM app_car WHERE price BETWEEN %s AND %s HAVING distance<=%s ORDER BY distance ASC"

cars = Car.objects.raw(query, [lat, lat, lon, min_price, max_price, miles])

return HttpResponse( cars )
```

And its returning

```
Car_Deferred_model_id_user_id object
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the 'len()' function. This would give:

```
query = "SELECT *, ((ACOS(SIN(%s * PI() / 180) * SIN(lat * PI() / 180) + COS(%s * PI() / 180) * COS(lat * PI() / 180) * COS((%s - lon) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS distance FROM app_car WHERE price BETWEEN %s AND %s HAVING distance<=%s ORDER BY distance ASC"

cars = Car.objects.raw(query, [lat, lat, lon, min_price, max_price, miles])

return HttpResponse(len(list(cars))
```

Aside: there's some useful information on the Django 1.2 Model.objects.raw() method at: http://djangoadvent.com/1.2/smoothing-curve/ [Looks like that site might have expired, but the Internet Archive has it at: http://web.archive.org/web/20110513122309/http://djangoadvent.com/1.2/smoothing-curve/ ]

Comment: Getting this error 
object of type 'RawQuerySet' has no len()

Comment: len(list(cars)) seems to work after i cast the object as a list

Comment: I'm also wondering whether it would be possible to optimise this by using 'SELECT COUNT(*)' (assuming all you need is the row count and not the rows themselves). I do not have 1.2 installed at present so cannot try it.

Comment: Ah no - that gives an InvalidQuery exception

Comment: If you just want the count, use SELECT COUNT(*) as @msanders points out, but don't use Car.objects.raw because that says you want Car objects as the result. Since you don't want that, use django.db.connection to get a cursor and execute the code directly, then fetch the single number result for the output.

Answer (score 8):

Truth be told, if all you want is the total number of records in the RawQuerySet, then by all means you should avoid casting the RawQuerySet into a list.

Casting the RawQuerySet into a list will iterate through each record matching the query. This is potentially burdensome for the server. Use count(*) instead. This can be achieved by wrapping count(*) around the raw SQL you used to spawn the RawQuerySet.

I used this to solve the problem:

```
def add_len_protocol_to_raw_sql_query( query ):
    """
    Adds/Overrides a dynamic implementation of the length protocol to the definition of RawQuerySet for the remainder of this thread's lifespan
    """
    from django.db.models.query import RawQuerySet
    def __len__( self ):
        from django.db import connection
        sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (' + query + ') B;'
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute( sql )
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        return row[ 0 ]
    setattr( RawQuerySet, '__len__', __len__ )
query = 'SELECT * FROM A_TABLE_OF_MINE'
add_len_protocol_to_raw_sql_query( query )
```

This makes a dynamic modification to RawQuerySet so that it responds to the len() protocol.

This is much better in terms of performance, thou there is potential for one drawback: If you use RawQuerySet more than once, then it would be desirable to discard the dynamic **_*len*_** implementation.

Do any of you know if the **_*len*_** method will be constrained by the caller's execution context? If using MOD_WSGI on Apache, does this means that all threads in the caller's process will share the modified definition?

Comment: What's that "B;" thing at the end of your outer query?

Comment: @ogurets The 'B' gives the subquery a name.  In this context, the subquery has to be named, even if it's just a junk name.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the improved solution that is based on user871977's:

```
from django.db import connection

def get_len(rawqueryset):
    def __len__(self):
        params = ["""'%s'""" % p for p in self.params]
        sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (' + (rawqueryset.raw_query % tuple(params)) + ') B;'
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql)
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        return row[0]
    return __len__

rawqueryset = .... # a RawQuerySet instance
setattr(type(rawqueryset), '__len__', get_len(rawqueryset))
```

Comment: Instead of manually injecting params into the sql string should just pass them into `cursor.execute(sql, self.params)`

Comment: @serg  call `cursor.execute(sql, [params])` if based on Django doc at `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly`. Thanks!

Comment: You can also replace `rawqueryset.raw_query % tuple(params)` by `self.query.__str__()`

Comment: I wanna thank you for ur post, I posted a solution here adding a piece of code that belongs to you :) :  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77108721/5322871)

Answer (score 2):

The reason there is no 'count' is because you would need an extra "count(*)" query to the database to know the size of your result set.

So bear in mind that calling `list(cars)` is loading all your results into memory. This allows you to get the count with `len`, but may be an expensive operation if you have a large result set.

Comment: This only works if the query returns at least one row, for otherwise the count will not be anywhere :-)