# Django: Paginator + raw SQL query

Tags: python, sql, django, pagination

I'm using Django Paginator everywhere on my website and even wrote a special template tag, to make it more convenient. But now I got to a state, where I need to make a complex custom raw SQL query, that without a `LIMIT` will return about 100K records.

**How can I use Django Pagintor with custom query?**

Simplified example of my problem:

My model:

```
class PersonManager(models.Manager):

    def complicated_list(self):

        from django.db import connection

        #Real query is much more complex        
        cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM `myapp_person`""");  

        result_list = []

        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            result_list.append(row[0]); 

        return result_list


class Person(models.Model):
    name      = models.CharField(max_length=255);
    surname   = models.CharField(max_length=255);     
    age       = models.IntegerField(); 

    objects   = PersonManager();
```

The way I use pagintation with Django ORM:

```
all_objects = Person.objects.all();

paginator = Paginator(all_objects, 10);

try:
    page = int(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
except ValueError:
    page = 1

try:
    persons = paginator.page(page)
except (EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
    persons = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
```

This way, Django get very smart, and adds `LIMIT` to a query when executing it. But when I use custom manager:

```
all_objects = Person.objects.complicated_list();
```

all data is selected, and only then python list is sliced, which is VERY slow. How can I make my custom manager behave similar like built in one?

Comment: In Python, you shouldn't use whitespace whenever you want like in your Person class.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looking at Paginator's source code, [page() function](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/core/paginator.py) in particular, I think that it's only matter of implementing [slicing](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getslice__) on your side, and translating that to relevant LIMIT clause in SQL query. You might also need to add some caching, but this starts to look like QuerySet, so maybe you can do something else:

- you can create database VIEW using CREATE VIEW myview AS [your query];
- add Django model for that VIEW, with [Meta: managed=False](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/options/#managed)
- use that model like any other model, including slicing its querysets - this means it's perfectly suitable for using with Paginator

(For your information - I've been using this approach for a long time now, even with complex many-to-many relationships with VIEWs faking m2m intermediate tables.)

Comment: Wow, thats cool :) Thank's for the reply, but I guiess I'm looking in a wrong directions. I've asked another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532686/django-getting-the-list-of-related-records-for-a-list-of-objects

Guiess custom managers are not the best thing here.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a `RawPaginator` class I made that overrides `Paginator` to work with raw queries. It takes one additional argument, `count`, which is the total count of your query. It doesn't slice the `object_list` because you must paginate in your raw query via `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`.

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

class RawPaginator(Paginator):
    def __init__(self, object_list, per_page, count, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(object_list, per_page, **kwargs)
        self.raw_count = count

    def _get_count(self):
        return self.raw_count
    count = property(_get_count)

    def page(self, number):
        number = self.validate_number(number)
        return self._get_page(self.object_list, number, self)
```

Comment: Very nice solution. Thank you.

Comment: When you call the new Paginator class, what value will `count` take when given as an argument?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Django 1.1 but if you can wait for 1.2 (which shouldn't be that long anymore) you can make use of `objects.raw()` as described in [this article](http://djangoadvent.com/1.2/smoothing-curve/) and in the [development documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/).

Otherwise, if you query is not too complex, maybe using the [`extra` clause](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/querysets/#queryset-extra) is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for a usefull tip. But I guess it does't help in my situation

Comment: You still can't get count for a raw query results. It looks like you actually have to do list(objects.raw()) for it to work with paginator. Thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317452/django-count-rawqueryset for that info.

Answer (score 2):

I also wanted to plug a [`PaginatedRawQuerySet`](https://gist.github.com/eltongo/d3e6bdef17b0b14384ba38edc76f25f6) which I wrote (please consider this as an alpha version). This adds the slicing ability to a raw queryset. Please refer [to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43921793/1973164) – which I wrote for another question with a similar requirement – in order to understand how it works (especially the "A word of caution" section in the end).

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import sql
from django.db.models.query import RawQuerySet


class PaginatedRawQuerySet(RawQuerySet):
    def __init__(self, raw_query, **kwargs):
        super(PaginatedRawQuerySet, self).__init__(raw_query, **kwargs)
        self.original_raw_query = raw_query
        self._result_cache = None

    def __getitem__(self, k):
        """
        Retrieves an item or slice from the set of results.
        """
        if not isinstance(k, (slice, int,)):
            raise TypeError
        assert ((not isinstance(k, slice) and (k >= 0)) or
                (isinstance(k, slice) and (k.start is None or k.start >= 0) and
                 (k.stop is None or k.stop >= 0))), \
            "Negative indexing is not supported."

        if self._result_cache is not None:
            return self._result_cache[k]

        if isinstance(k, slice):
            qs = self._clone()
            if k.start is not None:
                start = int(k.start)
            else:
                start = None
            if k.stop is not None:
                stop = int(k.stop)
            else:
                stop = None
            qs.set_limits(start, stop)
            return qs

        qs = self._clone()
        qs.set_limits(k, k + 1)
        return list(qs)[0]

    def __iter__(self):
        self._fetch_all()
        return iter(self._result_cache)

    def count(self):
        if self._result_cache is not None:
            return len(self._result_cache)

        return self.model.objects.count()

    def set_limits(self, start, stop):
        limit_offset = ''

        new_params = tuple()
        if start is None:
            start = 0
        elif start > 0:
            new_params += (start,)
            limit_offset = ' OFFSET %s'
        if stop is not None:
            new_params = (stop - start,) + new_params
            limit_offset = 'LIMIT %s' + limit_offset

        self.params = self.params + new_params
        self.raw_query = self.original_raw_query + limit_offset
        self.query = sql.RawQuery(sql=self.raw_query, using=self.db, params=self.params)

    def _fetch_all(self):
        if self._result_cache is None:
            self._result_cache = list(super().__iter__())

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self.model.__name__)

    def __len__(self):
        self._fetch_all()
        return len(self._result_cache)

    def _clone(self):
        clone = self.__class__(raw_query=self.raw_query, model=self.model, using=self._db, hints=self._hints,
                               query=self.query, params=self.params, translations=self.translations)
        return clone
```