# Django getting list of records (with FK) related to object -not rendering template correctly

Tags: django

I am trying to follow this previous question here:
[Django: getting the list of related records for a list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532686/django-getting-the-list-of-related-records-for-a-list-of-objects)

but can't seem to get it to work.

I get a list of owners but do not get a list of pet names. The html code doesn't seem to execute the 2nd FOR loop. Any ideas?

**models.py**

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
        teacher = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name="teacher")

        def __unicode__(self):
          return self.teacher

class Owner(models.Model):
        relevantteacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, verbose_name="teacher")       
        owner = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name="owner")

        def __unicode__(self):
          return self.owner

class PetName(models.Model):
        relevantowner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, verbose_name="owner")
        pet_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="pet Name")

    def __unicode__(self):
      return self.pet_name
```

**views.py**

```
def ownersandteachers(request):   
   owners = Owner.objects.all()

   context = {'owners': owners}
   return render(request, 'ownersandpets.html', context)
```

**template**

```
{% for i in owners %}
    {{ i.owner }} has pets:<br />
    {% for v in owners.petname_set.all %} //this doesn't seem to be executing
     - {{ v.pet_name }}<br />
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing

```
{% for v in owners.petname_set.all %}
```

where you should be doing

```
{% for v in i.petname_set.all %}
```

`owners` is the queryset, but you need to get the `petname_set` for the individual object in the queryset which is `i` in this case.

Also, I would recommend a condition check if `i.petname_set` exists. If not, do not show the `has pets:` text.

```
{% for i in owners %}
    {{ i.owner }} 
    {% if i.petname_set.count %} has pets:<br />
        {% for v in i.petname_set.all %} //this doesn't seem to be executing
         - {{ v.pet_name }}<br />
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```