# Django charfield queryset filter without escaping the MYSQL wildcard

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm looking for a way to do this:

```
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(mystring__like="____10____")

#Which would create a sql clause
... LIKE '____10____'
```

instead of behave like this:

```
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(mystring__icontains="____10____")
#Which creates a sql clause
... LIKE %\_\\_\\_\\_10\\_\\_\\_\\_%
```

I know I can use a regex filter, but that's substantially slower and more error prone than just using the built-in mysql wildcard feature (I've tested it directly in mysql, the query strings are long enough that the difference is substantial).

---

EDIT:
figured out how to do this with the .extra() method with madisvain's help.

```
qs = MyModel.objects.extra(where=["`mystring` LIKE '____10____'"])
```

In terms of performance difference, 2000 random queries with the regex approach took 20.5 seconds, with this approach 2000 random queries take 6 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't even know django had this __like version. Well but according to the docs please read this!
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#escaping-percent-signs-and-underscores-in-like-statements

You should be writing the query like this.

```
    qs = MyModel.objects.filter(mystring__contains="____10____")
```

Or this.

```
    qs = MyModel.objects.extra(where="mystring LIKE '____10____'")
```

Read more about the extra() method here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra

Comment: ah, sorry, I was unclear.  I want to get something like a raw Like.  the __contains is going to escape the underscore for us.  Its a great safety feature, but I want to be able to turn it off.

Comment: found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317452/django-count-rawqueryset  you can get a length by doing len(list(rawQS)).  but there goes any performance improvement

Comment: For that you could use the extra method provided.

`Entry.objects.extra(where="mystring LIKE '____10____'")`

Comment: there are a couple typos in your second answer that makes the format crash, while the approach works.  It should be: `where=["'mystring' LIKE '____10____'"]` except the quotes around mystring should be `

Comment: can you make an edit to this question so I can upvote it?  I inadvertently clicked downvote when I wanted to accept and my vote is currently locked.

Comment: sure! Done, dont worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `raw()` manager to preform raw SQL queries, so the line would become:

```
qs = MyModel.objects.raw("SELECT * from MyApp_MyModel where mystring like %s", [variable])
```

Comment: Its definitely an option, but I've never liked raw querysets.  Unless they've got an attribute I'm unaware of it's not possible to tell if they have data, their length, or if you got an error

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to [regex filter function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#regex) or case insensitive [iregex version](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iregex). Example:

```
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(mystring__regex="....10....")
```

Disadvantage: you may check regex support for the backend you use, impact to performance and in the case of backend change this could cause potential problems: *the regular expression syntax is that of the database backend in use*.