# how to set pagination in SQL query as per page?

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-rest-framework

how to set pagination as per page in SQL query, i tried with django default pagination but it didn't worked in my code and i am direct fetching data using SQL raw-query instead of ORM. i think the another way is set pagination using SQL query LIMIT or OFFSET but i have no idea about url-endpoint when i am searching next-page.

```
class Order_ListAPIView(APIView):

    def get(self,request,format=None):

        if request.method == 'GET':
            cur,conn = connection()
            order_query = ''' SELECT * FROM orders'''
            order_detail_query = ''' SELECT * FROM order_details'''

            with conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor) as cursor:

                cursor.execute(order_query)
                order_result = cursor.fetchall()
                order_data = list(order_result)

            ...
             ... #rest_code
              ...


            return Response({"order_data":order_data},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to paginate a raw SQL query in a Django REST ListAPI view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32191853/best-way-to-paginate-a-raw-sql-query-in-a-django-rest-listapi-view)

Comment: i didn't get any helpful in this link @MKPatel

Comment: There is any reason for using `sql` instead of `ORM`.

Comment: cause my senior developer made decision to use sql-query method

Comment: seeing if request.method == 'GET': inside get() method is weird

Comment: i didn't get understood @MahmoudAdel

Comment: @anonymoususer you already in get() function so it doesn't make sense to check if request.method is GET because you already go to get() method when the request verb is GET

Comment: i repeated that just because of to use custom Response. @MahmoudAdel

Comment: then make your custome response based on the data itself, check if the data returend being empty or not and then return your desired response

Comment: now see this [link](https://pastebin.com/zijJUhAD) @MahmoudAdel

Comment: it's still doesn't work as per above links @MahmoudAdel

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with Django, but as you say, you're fetching the data raw yourself from the DB with MySQL, so to setup pagination it should be as simple as adding `LIMIT $offset, $perpage` to your MySQL query...

```
SELECT * FROM order_details LIMIT 0, 5;
```

This query, for instance, would get you PAGE 1, with 5 PER PAGE.  To get to page 5 with 5 per page, it's `LIMIT 4*5, 5` = `LIMIT 25, 5`.  If you wanted to get to page 37 with 10 per page, it would be `LIMIT 36*10, 10` = `LIMIT 360, 10`.

This should solve the pagination issue with the MySQL part.  You'll need to setup vars to determine both `page` and `perpage` from the user, probably from a GET param.